# How can I send a multi-part email with text/plain and text/html parts with Grails?

Tags: email, grails, mime

I've looked through the code and documentation for the Grails Mail plugin (version 0.9) and it doesn't have the support I'm looking for. You can only set a single body and then provide a mime attachment that points to a static file.  I need to actual pass a model into a GSP and have it render both the HTML and plain text versions and then have those both available in the message. This will allow non-HTML-based e-mail clients to display the text/plain part and clients that support HTML to display the text/html part.

Has anybody done this with Grails? Is there an easy way to do it, or do I have to modify the mail plugin or just go to the Java Mail library directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since version 1.0 the mail plugin natively supports multipart alternative content as described in http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMAIL-37

```
mailService.sendMail {
    multipart true
    to <recipient>
    subject <subject string>
    text 'my plain text'
    html '<html><body>my html text</body></html>'
}
```

Comment: I'm not working with Grails right now, so I don't have the time to test this out, but I'll take your word for it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

We use multipart email with the standard email plugin. The following code snippet is located in a service class, that's why we're using standard groovy templating instead of the gsp engine:

```
        Template template = groovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(<templatename>)
        Writable emailBody = template.make(<data model as map>)
        StringWriter bodyWriter = new StringWriter()
        emailBody.writeTo(bodyWriter)

        String xml = <some xml>  

        mailService.sendMail {
            multipart true
            to <recipient>
            subject <subject string>
            body bodyWriter
            attachBytes "filename.xml", "text/xml", xml.getBytes('UTF-8')
        }
```

The crucial thing is that 'multipart true' appears at the beginning of the closure. If you add

```
html '<b>Hello</b> World'
```

to the closure above, I assume you'll get a text and html email with an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is potential content of version 1.0 of the Mail plugin, see [this](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-2237) and [this](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-2606) issue. Looking at the patch of the first issue, I think an html and text multipart message could simply be created like this:

```
mailService.sendMail {
  multipart true
  to <recipient>
  subject <subject>
  dualBody(template:<template>, model:<model>)
}
```

Would be pretty cool! No idea if / when this will be released though.